# How to pass a variable from Rmd file to a latex file

Tags: r, knitr

I have two file **1. index.rmd** file and the other is **2.Preamble.tex** file
I want to delclare a variable in **index.rmd** i.e.

```
a <- 'Start and end with single quote'
```

I want to pass the above variable in **preamble.tex**

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand\CenterHeader{>>>>**a(variable)**<<<<<}
```

It can be an **rmd** file or a **r** file

how do I achieve this

Answer (score 1):

First, create `preamble.Rnw`:

```latex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand\CenterHeader{\Sexpr{a}}
```

Then in `index.Rmd`, compile `preamble.Rnw` after you have created `a`:

````
```{r}
a <- 'Start and end with single quote'
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
xfun::Rscript_call(function() {
  knitr::knit('preamble.Rnw', envir = list(a = a))
})
```
````

This will generate `preamble.tex`.