# How do I assign these variables from Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio, rmarkdown

I have variables that are going to be dynamic in this document. How do I assign theme from Rmarkdown.

Below is how my .tex file looks like

[image]

So for example `$District_Name$` is a dynamic variable.
I want to change it through rmarkdown.
Below is what my YAML header looks like so far

[image]

I get an error when I try to run it like this. What I'm missing here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a variable from Rmd file to a latex file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/566929/how-to-pass-a-variable-from-rmd-file-to-a-latex-file)

Comment: So I just tried to declare the variable as a parameter in the header and that worked..